# Rich Text Editor and Inserting Images getting error

Tags: umbraco

When i click on 'Insert Picture' in a Rich Text Editor, the box that comes up displays a server error ... (see below)

```
    Server Error in '/' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


[No relevant source lines]

Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\9859ef3d\cb984e77\App_Web_uploadmediaimage.ascx.c3c18f9f.sp-vjjqb.0.cs    Line: 0 

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   umbraco.cms.businesslogic.datatype.DataTypeDefinition.GetByDataTypeId(Guid DataTypeId) +77
   umbraco.controls.Images.UploadMediaImage..ctor() +88
   ASP.umbraco_controls_images_uploadmediaimage_ascx..ctor() in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\9859ef3d\cb984e77\App_Web_uploadmediaimage.ascx.c3c18f9f.sp-vjjqb.0.cs:0
   ASP.umbraco_plugins_tinymce3_insertimage_aspx.__BuildControlMediaUploader() in c:\SequreDev\SQDev\Umbraco\plugins\tinymce3\insertImage.aspx:187
   ASP.umbraco_plugins_tinymce3_insertimage_aspx.__BuildControlpane_upload() in c:\SequreDev\SQDev\Umbraco\plugins\tinymce3\insertImage.aspx:186
   ASP.umbraco_plugins_tinymce3_insertimage_aspx.__BuildControlForm1() in c:\SequreDev\SQDev\Umbraco\plugins\tinymce3\insertImage.aspx:150
   ASP.umbraco_plugins_tinymce3_insertimage_aspx.__BuildControlTree(umbraco_plugins_tinymce3_insertimage_aspx __ctrl) in c:\SequreDev\SQDev\Umbraco\plugins\tinymce3\insertImage.aspx:1
   ASP.umbraco_plugins_tinymce3_insertimage_aspx.FrameworkInitialize() in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\9859ef3d\cb984e77\App_Web_insertimage.aspx.43b758d9.m5dvbuf5.0.cs:0
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +71
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +268
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +166
   ASP.umbraco_plugins_tinymce3_insertimage_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\9859ef3d\cb984e77\App_Web_insertimage.aspx.43b758d9.m5dvbuf5.0.cs:0
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +624
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +269

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found that this issue can be caused by a corrupted data type. Have a look at this Umbraco form post:

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/39103-Problem-with-Rich-Text-Editor-and-Inserting-Images

I found that when I went through my datatypes one at a time the 301 redirect was throwing an error. When I deleted this the Media picker in the RTE was showing again

I hope this helps.

L

Comment: I manually clicked every datatype and deleted the ones that were throwing exceptions and everything went back to normal. +1