# Cannot Insert image through Umbraco RichText editor

Tags: umbraco, rich-text-editor

The problem regarding richtext editor in Umbraco 4.

I am not able to add images through the RichText editor. When i click on the add image icon on the rich text editor, the popup panel displays an error (find in resource number 2).

The RichText editor datatype is using Tinymce3 as its type.

The resources ihave used and did not solve the problem.

1) http://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/39103-Problem-with-Rich-Text-Editor-and-Inserting-Images

2) [Rich Text Editor and Inserting Images getting error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338746/rich-text-editor-and-inserting-images-getting-error)

What i have done(they did not work):

a) resaved the RichText editor datatype with different Type,

b) deleted the RichText editor(bad mistake) and recreated it,

c) copied the code of insertimage.aspx from different projects wherever the RichText editor is working,

Kindly, have a look at the error image i have attached with this question.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

**Error**

Server Error in '/' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

[No relevant source lines]

Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1096afd0\6b67abfd\App_Web_uploadmediaimage.ascx.c3c18f9f.5y91thdt.0.cs    Line: 0

Stack Trace:

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   umbraco.cms.businesslogic.datatype.DataTypeDefinition.b__0(DataTypeDefinition x) +235
   System.Linq.WhereArrayIterator`1.MoveNext() +42
   umbraco.cms.businesslogic.datatype.DataTypeDefinition.GetByDataTypeId(Guid DataTypeId) +311
   umbraco.controls.Images.UploadMediaImage..ctor() +88
   ASP.umbraco_controls_images_uploadmediaimage_ascx..ctor() in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1096afd0\6b67abfd\App_Web_uploadmediaimage.ascx.c3c18f9f.5y91thdt.0.cs:0
   ASP.umbraco_plugins_tinymce3_insertimage_aspx.__BuildControlMediaUploader() in c:\work\IU\trunk\src\International.Web.UI\umbraco\plugins\tinymce3\insertImage.aspx:187
   ASP.umbraco_plugins_tinymce3_insertimage_aspx.__BuildControlpane_upload() in c:\work\IU\trunk\src\International.Web.UI\umbraco\plugins\tinymce3\insertImage.aspx:186
   ASP.umbraco_plugins_tinymce3_insertimage_aspx.__BuildControlForm1() in c:\work\IU\trunk\src\International.Web.UI\umbraco\plugins\tinymce3\insertImage.aspx:150
   ASP.umbraco_plugins_tinymce3_insertimage_aspx.__BuildControlTree(umbraco_plugins_tinymce3_insertimage_aspx __ctrl) in c:\work\IU\trunk\src\International.Web.UI\umbraco\plugins\tinymce3\insertImage.aspx:1
   ASP.umbraco_plugins_tinymce3_insertimage_aspx.FrameworkInitialize() in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1096afd0\6b67abfd\App_Web_insertimage.aspx.43b758d9.qhb5uafm.0.cs:0
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +67
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +118
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +98
   ASP.umbraco_plugins_tinymce3_insertimage_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1096afd0\6b67abfd\App_Web_insertimage.aspx.43b758d9.qhb5uafm.0.cs:0
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +912
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +164

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18033

Answer (score 0):

Two things that spring to mind:

**Permissions**

I would do the usual housekeeping check first. Ensure that the following accounts have modify permission on all of the site's folders:

1. NETWORK SERVICE
2. IUSR
3. IIS_IUSRS

**Corrupted install**

A final resort would be a re-install. Copy over all the files from your version of Umbraco. If this still doesn't work, point it at a new database and try re-installing a basic Umbraco website.

The idea here is to determine if it is a corrupted database record, or a missing/corrupted file.

Is the site a new one? Have you always stuck with the same version or recently upgraded?

Let us know if you have your own answer too please. Best of luck!